# Как заменить количество пробелов (если их больше 1) в строке на определенное количество?

Tags: c++, winforms, строки, форматирование

Как заменить количество пробелов (если их больше 1) в строке на определенное количество (скажем на 2 пробела)?

Upd: допустим, есть строка:

```
32       12  6              9   366
```

Необходимо привести её к виду

```
32 12 6 9 366
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой вопрос своими попытками справиться с данной проблемой. [**Аргументация**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), почему это нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: И что вы хотите получить из этой строки? "Ичтовыхотитеполучить из этой строки?" Или "И чтовыхотитеполучитьизэтой строки?" При отсутствии внятного ТЗ результат всегда ХЗ...

Comment: @Harry По всей видимости, имеется в виду все длинные пробелы сделать двойными.

Comment: @bipll Мы здесь не гаданием занимаемся :)

Comment: @СашаЧерных В чем смысл давать ссылку на англиский сайт? Тем более, что вы даже вопрос не минуснули.

Comment: @Harry Но-но, это не гадание, а восстановление семантики текста по разрозненным обрывкам! 8->

Answer (score 1):

Тег `c++` подсказывает, что можно использовать std::regex, в частности, [std::regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace).

Ну либо по старинке циклом по всей строке со вспомогательным итератором: перебирается каждый символ, и если это не третий (и далее) подряд пробел, его значение копируется в итератор и итератор растет, а под конец строка обрубается по итоговому значению итератора.

Answer (score 1):

Покажу один из способов:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
string&  response(string& s)
{
   istringstream is(s);
   s.clear();
   using It = istream_iterator<string>;
   s = std::accumulate(It(is), It(), s,
                   [](string& s1, const string& s2){ s1 += s2 + "  "; return s1;});
   return s;
}
```

функция возвратит нужную вам строку

Comment: Единичные пробелы тоже заменит, а ОП об этом не просил. Не говоря уже о неизвестно откуда взявшемся двойном пробеле в конце строки.